# Problems Concatenate large number of CSV which are different

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have 15,000 CSV files which I am trying to Concatenate into a single one.

**Problem 1 / CSV file 1**
This is the first CSV, it is the oldest one I am merging and therefore has the least amount of data / columns. Below is an example of the CSV.

```
TIME                  Val1    Val2     Val3
08-Jul-2002 11:28:23 0.000000 0.000000 110
08-Jul-2002 11:29:02 0.000000 0.000000 110
```

Notice that there is four headers of data, but 5 columns of data? So there is a TIME column, but the data for DATE and TIME is seperated. Okay, so I use this code, below, which **works** and I can join together any CSV which is similar.

**INPUT**

```
#Using GLOB to read every single CSV in a folder 
import glob
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np
import os

path = r'C:\Users\Will\merge_test'
# use your path
files = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")
files.sort(key=os.path.getmtime)
files

li = []

for filename in files:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None, header=0, sep = ' ',
                    names=['Date', 'Time', 'Val1', 'Val2', 'Val3'])

    li.append(df)

data = pd.concat(li, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```

**Output:**

```
     Date         Time      Val1 Val2 Val3
0   08-Jul-2002 11:28:23    0.0 0.0 110.0
1   08-Jul-2002 11:29:02    0.0 0.0 110.0
2   08-Jul-2002 11:30:00    0.0 0.0 110.0
```

So **Problem 1** can be solved by naming the columns, however it creates Problem 2

**Problem 2**

As mentioned, I am trying to Concatenate 15,000+ CSV files, most of which **share similar row data but have different column formatting** for example. I now want to start merging CSV files which not only has the date in a different column, but also has two entirely new columns (UniqueID and Val4)

Example of CSV file 2 (which has more data/columns)

```
Unique_ID   DATE       TIME     Val1     Val2     Val3       Val4
1007       20-FEB-2004 00:00:01 0.000000 0.000000 103.300000 0
```

If I change my input code to remove column names, it is able to read the CSV and Concatenate it with CSV1. However, it now messes up the date/time for CSV file 1.

**Code that has changed**

```
 df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None,encoding='utf-8', header=0, sep = ' ')
```

**Output**

```
          TIME      Val1    Val2    Val3    Val4 DATE   Val5
0       00:00:00    182.8   175.3   108.4   NaN  NaN    NaN
..............................................................
2875    23:55:01    0.0      0.0    102.5   1007 20-FEB-2004 0.0
```

**Questions**

- If I have 15,000 files with a **varying** number and placement of csv headers, is what I am trying to do too complicated?
- When I try to merge CSV files which have a different number of columns, I am not able to name the columns. I receive an error saying, 'expected 16 headers, saw 5'. Is there a way to resolve this? This is happening because obviously the CSV with 5 columns is being read first, but the code says there should be 16 columns.
- I'm not sure how I can fix the date/time issue. If the date and time data was always in the first two columns it wouldn't be a problem. I'm not sure how I can Concatenate the CSV files and keep the date/time data matching in the data frame.

Comment: You need to code for each one of these exceptions, process them to a standardised format, then concatenate and save. Computers are stupid, they only do what you tell them to do.

Comment: Your example CSV data is not shown in CSV format (you have replaced it with spaces) so it is harder to know where the boundaries are. I suggest you write a script to determine how many different formats there are for the files, as suggested each will need different logic. Are the columns names consistent?